# PHP does not work on my server but I need it for this session script I found somewhere

Tags: php, session

I am trying to add some security to my webpage.

My webpage "page.html" has lot of javascript scripts and html code. I can change extension to php. I have no problem with that.

I am using an example code I found on internet to understand how session_start works. If I have html extension, it works fine but I can access to the webpage even if I don't add user and pass. if I use php extension, webpage throws me to the login promt again. With php extension I can't access to the webpage when I write it on browser.

This is my code to check access: checkAccess.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//check the autenticated value
if ($_SESSION["autenticado"] != "si") {
//if doesn't exits, goes to login webpage
header("Location: login.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

And I added this line on the html and php webpage:

```
<?php include "checkAccess.php";?>
```

I know it works because I can access with my page in html. But when I change extension to php, it doesn't work.

Do I have to configure any value in php.ini or something like that?

I add my other php files to check session:

autenticacion.php:

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_POST["usuario"]=="user" && $_POST["contrasena"]=="123456"){
$_SESSION["autenticado"]= "SI";
header ("Location: mypage.php");
}else {
header("Location: login.php?errorusuario=si");
}
?>
```

login.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
<title>Autenticación PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Formulario de autenticaci&oacuten</h1>
<?php if(isset($_GET['errorusuario'])){if ($_GET['errorusuario']=="si"){?>
<font color="red"><b>Datos incorrectos</b></font>
<?php }}else{?>
Introduce tu nombre de usuario y contrase&ntildea
<?}?>
<form action="autenticacion.php" method="POST">
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Nombre de usuario:</td><td><input name="usuario" size="25" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contrase&ntildea:</td><td><input name="contrasena" size="25" type="password"/>      </td></tr>
<tr><td/><td><input type="submit" value="Inicio de sesión"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
Para ingresar, d&eacutebes ingresar <b>pablo</b> en el 1er campo y <b>123456</b> en el    2do.
</body>
</html>
```

I am using xampp to test page.

Comment: "works fine, but" is a clear sign that you don't understand the code. Additionally your question shows that you have limited  knowledge of PHP with your server (which is OK). Please show us that you get a phpinfo() page to run and link it with your question.

Comment: If it redirects to `login.php` when the file has the correct .php name extension, isn't that a sign that it *is* working correctly?

Comment: Can I upload a pdf here or I have to do it outside and post the link here? I did phpinfo().

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Q: Where is `$_SESSION["autenticado"]` being set?

Q: Did you do a `session_start()` there, as well?  You *MUST* call start_session() in *BOTH* pages.

Q: What do you see if you `echo` the value of `` `$_SESSION["autenticado"] ``?  Why not do a var_dump() of the entire $_SESSION[] array, and see if there's *anything* there?

Q: Did you enable cookies in your browser?

Here is a good tutorial on PHP sessions:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Here is the documentation for the $_SESSION[] superglobal (note the "isset($_SESSION)" function you should probably be using in your code):

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

And yes, there are session settings in php.ini.  But frankly, I wouldn't mess with any of them except as a last resort, and unless you knew exactly what you were doing.  Here's the documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: Please keep the answers high quality and not just comments, keep it like a real answer, not giving -1.

Comment: @ j08691 - "I wish that I could write you a melody so plain" - Bob Dylan ;)